Screen readers read the column header as one of the rows
Screen readers always read the column headers as one of the row. Let's say a table has three rows and one column header, then the screen reader reads it as 4 rows; this includes the column header + three rows.
I have even seen this issue in this example: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/grid/examples/data-grids/
I have pasted a simple table markup here:


<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Event</th>
    <th scope="col">Venue</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12 February</td>
    <td>Waltz with Strauss</td>
    <td>Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>12 February</td>
    <td>Waltz with Strauss</td>
    <td>Main Hall</td>
  </tr>
</table>



Can somebody please help me how to fix this issue?

What is the screen readers you are referring to? There are plenty ones, and they behave differently. Does using <thead> and <tbody> fix the issue?

I am using NVDA and JAWS, but both reads the same. I have tried  and , but the results are the same.

Ok now I’m uncertain about the question here. Are you concerned by the fact that also header rows are counted in the rowcount? Or that the header cells are not treated as headers and not read when navigating through data cells?

If you are using thead and tbody correctly, then whatever the result is is the expected behavior.

This isn't an issue. All screen readers consider the table headers as being part of the table and can be read and navigated as all other regular rows and columns.
This is perfectly normal and expected by screen reader users.

Exactly. The user is told what the table consists of before the data rows are read. This is expected.
